# How do I specify the hadoop2 version of avro-mapred in maven?

Tags: java, maven

The version of the jar I need is avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar. [Here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.avro|avro-mapred|1.7.7|bundle) is the list of builds on maven central. How do I tell Maven to get the hadoop2 version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`<classifier>`](http://java.dzone.com/articles/5-maven-tips) element. Like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-mapred</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
    <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Aside: Normally with an IDE (like Eclipse) when you try add a dependency with the gui dialog, it will show the list of the different ones you can choose from

[image]

Comment: and from command line: `mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:1.7.7:jar:hadoop2 -Dtransitive=false`

Comment: if somebody stucked with the same issue in Cloudera Hadoop Distribution (CDH) - you must do the same thing
`<groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-mapred</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6-cdh5.3.1</version>
            <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>`